# How to use TeamsBotSsoPrompt in Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework, teams-toolkit

My goal is to get an SSO token in a Teams bot. The code below is my try to get this working in the most basic way.
In response to any input, a waterfall dialog is executed which runs `TeamsBotSsoPrompt`. I verified all settings are correct and there is no exception.

The line `return await ssoPrompt.BeginDialogAsync(stepContext, _dialogState, cancellationToken);` executes without error.

Stepping into the code I find that `TeamsBotSsoPrompt` calls `await SendOAuthCardToObtainTokenAsync(dialogContext.get_Context(), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);` and that's the last event I see. There is no output in Teams.

The last sign of activity in my bot is then a call to my override `OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync()`.

The second step of the waterfall where I would get access to the token is never reached.

What do I have to do to get the token?

```cs
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using DataPlatformBot.SSO;
using Microsoft.TeamsFx.Bot;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.TeamsFx.Configuration;

namespace DataPlatformBot;

public class TeamsBot : TeamsActivityHandler
{
    readonly ILogger<TeamsBot> _logger;
    readonly SsoDialog _ssoDialog;
    readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> _dialogState;
    readonly BotAuthenticationOptions _botAuthOptions;
    readonly BotState _conversationState;
    
    public TeamsBot(ConversationState conversationState, IOptions<BotAuthenticationOptions> botAuthOptions, SsoDialog ssoDialog, ILogger<TeamsBot> logger)
    {
        _ssoDialog = ssoDialog;
        _logger = logger;

        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _dialogState = _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState");
        _botAuthOptions = botAuthOptions.Value;
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var wd = new WaterfallDialog("SsoWaterfall", new List<WaterfallStep> {
            async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => {
                var ssoSettings = new TeamsBotSsoPromptSettings(_botAuthOptions, new string[] { "User.Read" });
                var ssoPrompt = new TeamsBotSsoPrompt(nameof(TeamsBotSsoPrompt), ssoSettings);
                return await ssoPrompt.BeginDialogAsync(stepContext, _dialogState, cancellationToken);
            },
            async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => {
                var tokenResponse = (TeamsBotSsoPromptTokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
        });

        await wd.RunAsync(turnContext, _dialogState, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Receive invoke activity of teams sign in verify state");
    }

    
    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/How-to-enable-Single-Sign-on-in-Teams-Toolkit-for-Visual-Studio#for-teams-bot-applications) on how to implement SSO with TeamsFx SDK. You can find sample code [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/tree/dev/packages/fx-core/templates/plugins/resource/aad/auth/V3/Bot/SSO).